# reporting running totals

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix report, which has a single group. A group may run over several pages, so I need to transfer the previous page's balance, as the first line in the new page, then details, and a page total at the end of the page.

```
Group Header
Groups Balance from the previous page
Details
Groups Balance(including previous page values)
```

How can I achieve this, thanks for your time. suppose just listing two columns, debit amount, credit amount, and account code

```
Account code, Debit, Credit    
group1 (account code)
    balance 0,0
    group-1-detail-1, 10,  0
    group-1-detail-2, 20,  0
    totals (group-1-so-far)   30, 0
    end of page
    beginning of page
Account code, Debit, Credit
    group1
    balance    30,0
    group-1-detail-3, 10,  0
    group-1-detail-4, 0,  40
    totals (group-1-so-far)   40, 40
    end of page
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please tell us what you ran in to, which practical problems you couldn't solve.

Comment: well, I could not bring the sums on the previous page. My group balance is displayed same.